# In vue js only one list is appearing from template

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am in learning phase of `vue.js` and here is my `index.html` code as follows:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="app">
            <ul>
                <todo-item></todo-item>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <script src="index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

and code of `index.js` is as follows:

```
Vue.component('todo-item', {
  template: '<li>Todo 1</li><li>Todo 2</li>'
})

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app'
})
```

now in the output, I am getting only one `<li>Todo 1</li>` not the second Todo 2.
Can anyone let me know why it is happening?

In case I repeat the `<todo-item></todo-item>` in index.html then it is repeating Todo 1, should not it display Todo 2 after Todo 1?

Comment: Put your <ul> element in your template, then it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have gotten the answer, It was happening because

> Component template should contain exactly one root element.

and I was using two `<li>` in the same template without a root element.

So I have changed in the template as

```
template: '<ul><li>This is a todo</li><li>Another work</li></ul>'
```

and removed `<ul>` from index.html. It is working fine now.